# Python3 global dir

Tags: python, python-internals

When entering in the python3.6 shell `dir` produces the following:

```
>>> dir()
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

`__builtins__` produces all the built-in python methods, for example [those described here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), and `__name__` will (always?) be `__main__`. What about the others: are those ever populated when either (1) in the python interpreter; or (2) running a script: and if so, when?

Here's an example from running a python script called `temp.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (dir())
    print ("__annotations__: %s" % __annotations__)
    print ("__builtins__: %s" % __builtins__)
    print ("__cached__: %s" % __cached__)
    print ("__doc__: %s" % __doc__)
    print ("__file__: %s" % __file__)
    print ("__name__: %s" % __name__)
    print ("__package__: %s" % __package__)
    print ("__spec__: %s" % __spec__)
```

Running it:

```
$ python temp.py
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
 __annotations__: {}
__builtins__: <module 'builtins' (built-in)> # <== always populated
__cached__: None
__doc__: None
__file__: temp.py # <== populated if running from a file/script
__name__: __main__ # <== populated (always with main?)
__package__: None
```

How/when are `__annotation__`, `__cached__`, `__doc__`, `__package__` populated? And is `__name__` ever not `__main__` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "populated at the global-python level"? By the only interpretations I've come up with, either all those others have *already* been "populated at the global-python level" in your test, or `__builtins__` and `__name__` have not been "populated at the global-python level".

Comment: @user2357112 update the question a bit.

Comment: Some attributes are set at module import time (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading). It's still not really clear what the question is asking, you need to clarify "the global-python level".

Comment: @wim updated to say in the python interpreter to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__name__` is only `__main__` in the script that is being run. It holds the fully-qualified name of the module where it is accessed:

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> from logging import config
>>> config.__name__
'logging.config'
```

`__cached__` and `__package__` are [Import-related module attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#import-related-module-attributes).

[`__doc__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=__doc__#types.ModuleType.__doc__) holds the docstring of the current module or function.

`__annotations__` holds [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-variable-annotation) of globals.

Comment: how would you have a `__doc__` at the module level?

Comment: A string at the top of a module is it's docstring. See the example of docopt making use of this: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/blob/master/README.rst#docopt-creates-beautiful-command-line-interfaces